# question for python experts: code doesn't work when called with generators

Tags: python, generator

I have a small snippet that does not work in an inexplicable way.
The purpose is to generate all combinations of two or more sequences.
It works when called with lists, but it doesn't when called with generators.

```
def comb(seqs):
    if seqs:
        for item in seqs[0]:
            for rest in comb(seqs[1:]):
                yield [item] + rest
    else:
        yield []

if __name__=="__main__":
    x=[1,2]
    y=[3,4]
    print list(comb([x,y])) # prints [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]

    def gen1(): yield 1; yield 2
    def gen2(): yield 3; yield 4
    x=gen1()
    y=gen2()
    print list(comb([x,y])) # prints [[1, 3], [1, 4]  WHY ????
```

Comment: Side-note: Why don't you use `itertool.product`?

Comment: @Space_Cowboy: this is for my own edification. I want to understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you can only iterate over a generator once. In the line

```
for item in seqs[0]
```

When you get to the second element of the `gen1`, you make a recursive call to iterate over the elements of `gen2`. The problem is that you have already iterated over `gen2` in the previous recursive call, so it will not yield any items.

Comment: I accept your answer. Charles also gave me the right answer, but you were the first, thanks.

Comment: @Alain: Actually, Charles was the first to post the complete answer. I posted a short one and then expanded it.

Answer (score 7):

A generator is exhausted once it has generated everything that it is going generate whereas a list can be iterated through multiple times.

Your `comb` generator relies on being able to iterate through the second and later sequences that it is passed multiple times so won't work if these sequences are actually a generator.

Answer (score 2):

Fix:

```
def comb(seqs):
    if seqs:
        inner = list(comb(seqs[1:]))        
        for item in seqs[0]:
            for rest in inner:
                yield [item] + rest
    else:
        yield []
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at itertools in [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools), there you probably will find everything you need to create iterators for efficient looping